# How to derive new columns from the values of a given column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe like the following:

```
foo    bar    baz
  a      4      x
  b      3      x
  c      5      y
  b      5      y
  a      7      z
```

I'd like to obtain this:

```
bar_a    bar_b    bar_c    baz
    4     null     null      x
 null        3     null      x
 null     null        5      y
 null        5     null      y
    7     null     null      z
```

Is there some function build-in to Spark to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `pivot`:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy($"baz", monotonically_increasing_id().as("id"))
            .pivot("foo")
            .agg(first($"bar"))
            .drop("id")

df2.show
+---+----+----+----+
|baz|   a|   b|   c|
+---+----+----+----+
|  y|null|null|   5|
|  y|null|   5|null|
|  x|   4|null|null|
|  x|null|   3|null|
|  z|   7|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

If you want pretty column names:

```
val df3 = df2.toDF(df2.columns.map(c => if (df2.columns.drop(1).contains(c)) "bar_" + c else c):_*)

df3.show
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|baz|bar_a|bar_b|bar_c|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  y| null| null|    5|
|  y| null|    5| null|
|  x|    4| null| null|
|  x| null|    3| null|
|  z|    7| null| null|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I forgot to mention that I do have another column (`baz`), that needs to be preserved. I edited my question accordingly. Is this ok? Otherwise, I can revert my edit, accept your answer, and open a new question.

Comment: Ah, of course! Using `baz` in `groupBy` too totally makes sense. Thanks a lot!